# How to set dockerignore for specific step?

Tags: docker

I am creating a Dockerfile with 2 steps, one builder and one "final".

When I do:

```
COPY --from=builder /usr/app/* ./app
```

I want it to not copy the `src` folder and the `node_modules` folder.
How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean '_for specific step_'? `.dockerignore` is only respected by COPY

Comment: @LinFelix by step I mean the builder. Builder copies the files from my PC, there I want it to copy the `src` folder, then when the final step copies the files from `builder` I want it to not copy the `src` folder, and also the `node_modules` that builder created for himself

Comment: `.dockerignore` causes some files not to be included in the build context that's sent to the daemon. That context is expensive to send, so you do not have a per-step context.

Comment: I'm used to the build outputs being in a single `dist` or `build` subdirectory.  Can you `COPY --from=...` only that directory to the final stage?

Comment: @DavidMaze the JS build is in that folder, but there are other stuff outside that dir. Such as `misc` folder or `proto` or `config`